# Delphi: code after Application.Run does not execute if user reboots/shuts down

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have some code placed after "Application.Run;" which is normally run when the app shuts down. This point is never reached however when the user reboots or shuts Windows down.

Can this be solved without capturing WM_ENDSESSION? (and not involving any form, I'd like the code to remain after application.run at the end of the dpr)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

VCL already listens for `WM_ENDSESSION` (the hidden application window), and terminates the application when the session is ending. You can [add a terminate procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AddTerminateProc) in the .dpr (or elsewhere) which will be called among possible other terminate procedures:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  sysutils,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

function OnTerminate: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  // do some short work
end;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  AddTerminateProc(OnTerminate);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: This method actually has some nasty implications.. if for any reason a form is "stuck", OnTerminate might be called before the forms are destroyed, so say i.e I'm accessing some object on a form's close event, which is destroyed in the OnTerminate proc, we will get an exception. (i.e. I do a GET on a blocking socket that's bound to timeout in a few seconds, then I click the X to close the app, OnTerminate will be called before any forms are closed and destroyed). Ideally we should be able to leave the code after the .Run; why is it not executed in the event of a system shutdown?

Comment: @Hikari - You seemed to be looking some place decoupled from forms. If that's not the case, why not put your code in a message handler in that form? When TApplication receives a WM_ENDSESSION, it doesn't wait for the WM_QUIT message to terminate, that's why statements after Run does not run.